# How can a society punish someone who doesn't care about anything?

Tags: law-enforcement

Suppose there is a criminal who doesn't care about anything. He doesn't care about himself, his body, money, other people, the world, or anything else. Now suppose he goes and commits a crime.

Is there a way to make him pay for what he did?

Killing him won't affect him, since he doesn't care about his life. He doesn't care about his well being, his health, or his emotional state, so torturing him or trying to make him sad won't affect him.

Comment: What is the worldbuilding question here?  It's sort of like asking whether a rock that gets dislodged from the top of a cliff, falls and kills someone can be made to feel bad about it.  This is your world, if you want to make a particular character like a rock then you can.  The decisions of that character and the decisions of society (in particular that punishment is the priority in responding to law-breaking) are character choices, which are off topic for this site.

Comment: Something to consider is that "punishment" is only partially for the criminal. The other part is for society and the perception that the proverbial pound of flesh is being extracted.

Comment: You literally cannot, by definition, punish someone who doesn't care about the punishment. If they don't care, or are not affected by it, it's not a punishment. They're not being punished. Rewording your question could help make it clearer and easier for us to answer.

Comment: @shreyasm-dev I edited the question. I hope the phrasing is better.

Comment: The question seems wrong. Why would you *punish* them? What even is the goal of that? Most criminals aren't "punished" just for the sake of it. Incarceration protects society from the criminals. And reformation is there to let them re-enter society. What you're proposing is to just administer some corporal, or financial, or emotional or other retribution for...what, exactly?

Comment: @VLAZ this takes place in another culture. The society believes in an eye for an eye.

Comment: Criminal justice system

Comment: @VLAZ sorry. I thought the question included the details relevant to the question. I didn't know that I needed to put anything in there about why I was asking the question. I thought I just needed to put stuff about the parameters of the question.

Comment: This is a fairly common story question for cold blooded psychopaths, e.g. in kingsmen where they set up a scenario where you bond with an animal and then have to kill them.

Comment: "How do I make bananas purple?" is a complete question but without context, it's kind of useless. Like, paint them purple on a canvas or what? You've presented a question about punishing some individual. Without actual context for why should "punishment" even be considered. A criminal without regard for anything can be separated from the community. Solves the community problem. Doesn't solve the "punishment" problem because, honestly the community probably wouldn't care after they've dealt with the real issue.

Comment: Punishments for crimes are not just about making the criminal feel miserable. Killing this guy will not make him feel punished - death penalty never does after its application - but depending on the culture in his society, people might arguably feel safer. Also no tax money goes on supporting the guy in prison. I am mostly against capital punishment though.

Comment: @KerrAvon2055, this smells a lot like another post of the "infinity" user (https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9925/30492 )

Answer (score 3):

A criminal justice system - whether it is focused on rehabilitation or punishment - serves a function to society, not just to those who do not behave as society expects.

A criminal who does not care about anything is a problem only as long as laws are unable to cope with recidivism, and most justice systems quickly alter themselves to deal with recidivists.

However, the function of a criminal justice system is primarily to protect society from the criminals who choose not to live by the society's rules.  A thief may be imprisoned for a time or have his hand cut off.  That may be seen as punitive, but it also serves the purpose of reducing the thief's capability to steal.  A murderer may be imprisoned for life or be executed, but either way, that removes his ability to kill again.  Additionally, the visibility of the punishments serve as a deterrent to those who *do* care about such things.

Where recidivists are sentenced to longer terms of imprisonment or harsher punishments, that further reduces their ability to repeat their crimes, and that's what its about: Protecting society from the criminal.

If a criminal can be rehabilitated, that's a bonus that lets the people involved in dealing with them feel good, but ultimately rehabilitation is not necessary as long as society is protected from them.

Answer (score 0):

## Make him care about things.

Do an extensive analysis of his psychology and in prison set up some sort of scenario that appeals to him. Suppose, say, he cares about dogs- have a dog in there with him, and set up scenarios to slowly help them bond and emotionally connect.

Then kill the dog when he cares enough by torturing it to death in front of him.

Comment: It was recognised even in the times when such tactics were used that using such tactics leaves you with yet another damaged person - the torturer.

Comment: I am not sure the state in this case cares about that, but if they do you could just find someone who likes torturing animals.

Comment: This assumes that the person has the brain connections to actually have caring emotions about anything. There are some people lacking those.

Comment: Any plan could fail if you keep inventing reasons it will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the society's view of what punishment's purposes are and what the law actually is, several situations can occur.

If the nihilist in question has committed a capital offense, it doesn't matter how it feels about being executed. The penalty gets served and the nihilist dies. That is being punished!

If the nihilist committed any other offense, and the society merely wants the punishment to be served, then the nihilist pays whatever fine, serves however much time, and/or suffers reduced rights per the punishment. This is still a punishment, even if the nihilist doesn't care. It may not serve what other people's desires, but a punishment occured nonetheless.

If the society cares more about reforming criminals than punishments, which many do argue should be the point of incarceration and other penalties, then there is a problem. The jailers or justice system must figure out how to change this individual so they can understand why their actions were bad. It may be possible to change such a person, but there is no clear answer here.

Comment: That could work. That way, punishments still happen, even though the criminal doesn't care.

Answer (score 0):

**Psychoactives**

It seems the goal is to create misery or distress in the subject. But the subject does not care about anything. So locking them up will not case misery. They are also immune to pain, so sticking with hot needles won't work either.

I suggest chemical methods. Get the subject addicted to opiates. These things flood your brain with happy chemicals. Once their brain is nice and addicted, remove the opiates. The withdrawal symptoms will create a state of misery and distress.

Answer (score 0):

### Execute him and leave it to God

This was the rationale behind capital punishment for centuries, particularly when it came to hardened murderers, etc.

Man may not be able to dispense real justice, but the Almighty is. Of course, it's premised upon if your society believes in God.